# When installing locally (npm install .), can I have npm use my global packages?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm install .` it takes a while to build packages that contain c code like expresso (which depends on node-jscoverage). I realized that I can copy expresso from my global package directory (~/Developer/lib/node_modules/expresso) to ./node_modules/expresso in my current directory before running `npm install .` and it won't bother compiling it. Is there a way to tell npm to try to install packages from my global npm directory before fetching and building them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm to install packages from local position rather than from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298775/npm-to-install-packages-from-local-position-rather-than-from-web)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this command might help: [npm link](http://npmjs.org/doc/link.html)

Check out this: [npm to install packages from local position rather than from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298775/npm-to-install-packages-from-local-position-rather-than-from-web)