# npm to install packages from local position rather than from web?

Tags: node.js, npm

The problem drove me crazy, there is a package in npm database, but it has some bugs, which are already fixed in github, how could I make use of the fixed version(github version)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can install directly from the GitHub repository, even just using the GitHub username and the repository name:

`npm install LearnBoost/socket.io`

You can also add a [`<commit-ish>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_identifier_terminology), specifying e.g. a commit hash or a version tag, like so:

`npm install LearnBoost/socket.io#1.7.x`

Without a protocol, this will be interpreted as `git://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io`. You can also prefix the repo with `gitlab:`, `gist:` or `bitbucket:`, respectively. For more information, see [Using git URLs as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

You can install directly from a URL, example:

```
npm install https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tarball/master
```

You can find the URL on Github under "Downloads" on any project page. Select the "Download as tar.gz" link.

Or you can install a tarball:

```
npm install foo.tar.gz
```

See [npm install(1)](http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html).

**Edit:**

I should mention that this works equally well in `package.json` files. Specify the URL instead of the version in your dependencies, like so:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "http://example.com/foo.tar.gz",
  "bar": "1.2.x",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other temporary solution, get the github project and use `npm link` (http://npmjs.org/doc/link.html) to link the local folder obtained through git to your `node_modules` folder in your own project. Anyway in the end, you'll have to wait for the project maintainer to do a `npm publish`.

Answer (score 0):

Either add the module as a git sub-module (using [git submodule](http://help.github.com/submodules/)) to your project or tell the module maintainer to update the version and trigger a `npm publish` to update the npm repository.

When using the sub-module way, be aware that you cannot update the reference using `npm`-commands.